# How to determine if the elements in the range [start,stop) are all equal?

Tags: c++

This is the requirement for the code:

> Create a generic function `all_equal(start, stop)` that determines
> if the elements in the range `[start,stop)` are all equal. The function returns true or false. If the range is empty, true is returned. The arguments `start` and `stop` are bidirectional iterators.

The following is my code:

```
template <class Iterator>
Iterator all_equal(Iterator start, Iterator stop) {
    Iterator front = start;
    Iterator back = stop;
    while (front != back){
        if (*front == *back)
            return false;
        else {
            front++;
            back--;
        }
    }
}
```

The following is my feedback from a marker:

> You can't dereference back. And this would compare elements two-by-two without ensuring they're all equal.

Comment: Stop shouldn't be included, so you shouldn't dereference this

Comment: ... and the function should return `bool`, not `Iterator`.  And make sure you return something when you fall out of the end of your loop.

Comment: ... and `if (*front == *back) return false;` has a typo. Return `false` when at least two elements are equal? Probably not. To understand the feedback (after fixing the other bugs mentioned in the comments above), you could walk through your code for a vector like `{0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0}`. What will your function return?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, it makes a lot more sense now. And about @JVApen 's comment, can you explained in a bit more details. I am not sure what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: You said [start, stop), however, stop shouldn't be included in the range, yet you dereference this, if this comes from a vector/list, it's UB to dereference the end iterator

Comment: Also, as of C++20, `bool all_of( InputIt first, InputIt last, UnaryPredicate p )` is a thing :D https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of

Answer (score 2):

You need to return a `bool` not an `Iterator`.  And you are dereferencing the `stop` iterator on the 1st loop iteration, which will be *undefined behavior* if `stop` is the `end` iterator of a container.  And there is no need to dercrement the `stop` iterator at all, even though the requirement specifies it as a bidirectional iterator.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
template <class Iterator>
bool all_equal(Iterator start, Iterator stop) {
    if (start != stop) {
        auto &value = *start;
        while (++start != stop) {
            if (*start != value)
                return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a standard library algorithm for this. By default [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) will search for adjacent equal elements but it can also find non-equal elements by changing the comparison function.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

template <class Iterator>
bool all_equal(Iterator start, Iterator stop)
{
    return std::adjacent_find(start, stop, std::not_equal_to<>{}) == stop;
}
```

Note: this requires at lease C++14 because I used the transparent comparator form of [`std::not_equal_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/not_equal_to)

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`std::all_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of):

```
template <class Iterator>
/*constexpr*/ // in C++20
bool all_equal(Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    return std::all_of(begin, end, [begin](const auto& e){ return e == *begin(); });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> You can't dereference back.

In C++ we use a 1 past the end notation for our containers. This is reflected in your question.

```
[start, stop)
```

This is mathematical notation. The square bracket `[` means inclusive but the round bracket `')` means not inclusive. So `start` is inside the range and `stop` is outside the range.

In iterate over containers in the same way. The `stop` is one past the end of the range. You can not de-reference this value. The first time around the loop you do de-reference it here:

```
        if (*front == *back)
```

---

> And this would compare elements two-by-two without ensuring they're all equal.

Your code would find the following list all equal (assuming you fixed the back issue above) and the return type.

```
 [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You check both ends and move towards the middle.

---

> The function returns true or false.

No return at the end of the function.

```
            front++;
            back--;
        }
    }
}
```

So we never know if it works!

---

I like Remy's solution, though I prefer a precheck for empty and a `for` rather than `while`.

```
template <class Iterator>
bool all_equal(Iterator start, Iterator stop) {
    if (start == stop) {
        return true;
    }
    for (Iterator loop = start; loop != stop; ++loop) {
        if (*loop != *start) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your function should return `bool` which is `true` or `false`, not iterator. Second - you cannot dereference `stop` as it does not point to an element in the sequence. Third - you either increase `start` or decrease `stop` but not both at the same time. Function could be:

```
template <class Iterator>
bool all_equal(Iterator start, Iterator stop) {
    if( start == stop ) 
        return true;
    while( true ){
        auto tmp = start++;
        if( start == stop ) return true;
        if( *tmp != *start ) return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ain't this also indexing out of bounds?

Comment: @JVApen No, `start` is dereferenced only after compared to `stop`, increasing `start` has to be done until it becomes equal to `stop`, how else you would iterate over the range?

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't realize auto temp = start++; updates the start :( oversight from me